# Intellij auto import not working for Typescript

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin7

I've just started with `Vaadin` for creating a web app and I've loaded a project in `Intellij` but it seems it can't find from where to Import things if i'm inside a typescript file.

[image]

It should be

`import {css, customElement, html, LitElement} from "lit-element";`

but it doesn't work.

What do I need to do to configure the IDE to make it simple and find the imports?

**EDIT**

The `"lit-element"` which is underscored with red says `Cannot find module 'lit-element'`
Why, though ?!

Comment: Have you run `mvn` at least once to download all npm dependencies? It won't be able to find the dependencies before then.

Comment: hmm, i guess not if you're saying that should solve my problem. Could you elaborate please on what exactly I should do ?

Comment: do you have `lit-element` package installed and included in index? Also, does this module include typings (`d.ts` files) that are required to make the TypeScript compiling work?

Comment: @lena ... uhm... those questions went over my head, unfortunately. Could you elaborate please ? I'm new to all of this. I'm a mobile dev by trade, so ... :)

Comment: make sure that you have `node_modules/lit-element` folder in your project and that this folder is not marked excluded

Comment: @AndreiBogdan - I meant that once you run `mvn` once, the imports should work. What version of Vaadin are you running? Your tag suggests Vaadin 7. For the LitElement templates you're trying to use, you should be on Vaadin 17

Answer (score 0):

In order for automatic imports to work properly you need to ensure that the dependency is available locally.
Vaadin uses npm (or pnpm depending on the version) to manage Javascript dependencies such as LitElement. In your project you should find the files

- `package.json`
- `package-lock.json`

In order to LitElement to be available as an import ensure that it is listed in the `package.json`. If it is not present you can install it into your project by running `npm install --save lit-element` in your command line while in the same folder as your projects `package.json`.
If the file is listed in the `package.json` ensure that in the same directory as the file there is another directory called `node_modules`. This contains your Javascript dependencies. Inside `node_modules` you should see another folder called `lit-element`. If this is not present, run `npm install` from command line while in the same directory as your projects `package.json`

If this does not solve your issues you can try to delete the `node_modules` directory and redownloading your dependencies by running `npm install`.
If this does not work, ensure that the folder is not marked as excluded in your IntelliJ project settings.
If you're still facing issues, you could try running a `mvn clea install` and then starting the server, contrary to what [Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5705554/marcus) said, Vaadin automatically executes `npm install` not during `mvn clean install` (unless its a production build) but rather during server startup.

---

In your question you mention that you are new to Vaadin, in this case I would suggest not necessarily directly getting started with LitElement based components, especially since you mentioned in the comments that you're usually a mobile developer. It is very possible to develop great UIs using Vaadins Java based components and then migrate to using LitElement later once you're more comfortable with the framework/stack.

Also you should be on Vaadin 15+ (the current latest version is 18.0.6) in order for Vaadin to provide first class support for LitElement, these are not LTS releases and only receive updates for 4 months after initial release ([The Vaadin release cadence starting with Vaadin 15 is detailed in this blog post](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-15-and-beyond-an-insiders-look-at-vaadins-future)), hence I would be cautious about using them in production.